# PageFactory. How to separate page elements and steps

Tags: java, testing, selenium-webdriver, factory, pageobjects

I'm trying to use PageFactory methods and would like to separate classes with elements and methods. For instance I have a class with page elements:

```
public class LoginPageElements extends AbstractPage  {

@FindBy(id = "rwOAuthUserName")
public WebElement login;

@FindBy(id = "rwOAuthPassword")
public WebElement password;

@FindBy(id = "rwOAuthLogin")
public WebElement submit;


public LoginPageElements (WebDriver driver){
    super(driver);
}
```

and a class with page methods:

```
public class LoginPageSteps {

private LoginPageElements elements;

@Step
public void fillLogin(String value){
    elements.login.clear();
    elements.login.sendKeys(value);
}

@Step
public void fillPassword(String value){
    elements.password.clear();
    elements.password.sendKeys(value);
}

@Step
public void submitTheForm(String value) {
    elements.submit.click();
}
```

On previous page I cause the method for visiting my login page and initializing all the required elements:

```
    public LoginPageElements clickLoginButton(){
        loginButton.click();
        return PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPageElements.class);
}
```

But the thing is that now I can't write the test like:

```
@BeforeTest
public void testSetUp(){
    driver = DriverManager.getDriverFor("FF");
    CNBLoginPage onCNBStartPage = PageFactory.
         initElements(driver, CNBLoginPage.class);
    onCNBStartPage.
            clickLoginButton().
            fillLogin(login).
```

due to the fact that clickLoginButton() returns the LoginPageElements  class, but fillLogin() is in LoginPageSteps  class.

Could you please tell me how to return elements and classes properly here?

Comment: Why do u want to separate these? It makes sense to have page methods in the same file as the page elements!

Comment: But if the page is large and contains lots of elements to be used and lots of methods, the class will be too big and heavy, won't it?

Comment: Yes..but if the page is too large, then you can split the page in different PageObject/PageFactory files in some logical way. PageObjects Need not represent an entire page as said in its documentation https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects

Answer (score 0):

Just add `PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);` in the constructor of your AbstractPage class, so it will be like:

```
public AbstractPage (WebDriver driver){
    this.driver = driver;
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
}
```

and with this you wil not longer need to initialize your PageElements that extends your AbstractPage or any other class that extends other classes extending AbstractPage.

with this your `@BeforeTest`should be like:

```
@BeforeTest
public void testSetUp(){
    driver = DriverManager.getDriverFor("FF");
    LoginPageSteps steps = new LoginPageSteps(driver);
    steps.clickLoginButton();
    steps.fillLogin(login);
```